# Optional generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, parameters

I need to use an optional generic parameter for a function. This would be the normal function without the generic parameter:

```
void MyFunction (string myText, int optionalParameter = 0)
{
 //Do something
}
```

What I need is this:

```
void MyFunction<T> (string myText, T optionalGenericParameter = default(T))
{
  //Do something
}
```

Unfortunately the initialization to `default(T)` is throwing the following error "cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: Well you have to call it like this `MyFunction<int>("test")` or like this `MyFunction("test", 1)`, otherwise compiler has no way to guess what is the type of `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is telling you that the compiler is unable to guess what the type `T` is when calling the method. If you had passed in a value for `optionalGenericParameter` the compiler would know what the type was. Instead, you need to explicitly specify the type, for example:

```
MyFunction<string>("Hello world");
```

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean its just better to not make it optional ( just regular generic ) and pass there for example 0 ? Also, what if there was more optionals ( like three ), would it have to look like this ?

MyFunction<string, string, string>("Hello World");

Comment: If you pass in a value, then there won't be a need to specify the type any more and the compiler can infer it for you. If the method had additional generic types, you would need to specify them all if a single one couldn't be inferred.

Answer (score 14):

I run into this problem somewhat often, what I do is... Overload

```
void MyFunction (string myText)
{
    MyFunction (myText, 0); 
    // this works because C# will infer T as being int
}

void MyFunction<T> (string myText, T optionalGenericParameter)
{
  //Do something
}

/* usage example:
MyFunction("foo");
MyFunction("bar", new Tuple<string, int>("yay", 113));
// C# will infer that T is Tuple<string, int> here.
*/
```

Comment: Thats pretty good solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the type when you call the method if you do not supply the 2nd parameter.

```
// correct
MyFunction<SomeType>("hello");

// NOT correct
MyFunction("hello");
```